# xpath or css-selector nth of nth-child or position of last()

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors

`[id*='GwtGFD_'] > option:last-child` # CSS-Selector

and

`//*[contains(@id, 'GwtGFD_')]/option[last()]` # XPATH

both return an expected 2 results. I'd like to do something like `//*[contains(@id, 'GwtGFD_')]/option[last()][1]` and `//*[contains(@id, 'GwtGFD_')]/option[last()][2]` but `[1]` returns both elements instead. Same seems to be true for the css-selector equivalent.

How can I retrieve the first and last, or nth position, of `last()`?

The full xpaths for each expected positional [1] and [2] results are as follows:

```
 /html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/select[1]/option[37]
 /html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/select[2]/option[37]
```

So maybe I just need to get the `select[1]` and `select[2]` a different way but I haven't found it. I'd also like to understand why what I'd expect to work above isn't working and how I may be able to retrieve the nth position of the results of `last()`.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassed I found the answer so quickly, hours after trying many things and deciding to post for help here; I hope this helps someone else, and I'm definitely curious about better ways to achieve this...

I was able to get the desired results using the below examples:

```
[id*='GwtGFD_']:nth-child(1) > option:last-child
[id*='GwtGFD_']:nth-child(5) > option:last-child
//*[contains(@id, 'GwtGFD_')][1]/option[last()]
//*[contains(@id, 'GwtGFD_')][4]/option[last()]
```